# Outlook desktop ignores new window options

Tags: outlook, office-js

I am trying to open a new window from the Outlook Desktop application, and the open command is triggered from an Office 365 Outlook add-in. The window that is opened ignores all of the options passed through that window.open() command and just opens it in a new tab.

The URL is excluded from the appDomain in the manifest because I do not want this link to open in the app window but instead in a new browser window. This issue is not present in the outlook web app.

Is there any way to pass these options through?

```
status=no,
toolbar=no,
menubar=no,
scrollbars=yes,
location=no,
directories=no,
resizable=yes,
width=1000,
height=600
```

Answer (score 1):

The supported way for opening a new window in an Outlook Add-ins is to use the [displayDialogAsync API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync) (detailed guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).) Unfortunately, most of the options you have described are not supported by the options for displayDialogAsync API. You can, however, guarantee that the url is opened in a new window by setting `displayInIframe: false` in the API options.